# Row count based on CONVERT output

Tags: sql, sql-server, count

This is what I currently have:

[image]

What I am aiming for is a count of searches as follows...

[image]

My actual table has a DatetimeSelected DataTime field and I need to a count for dates only. I use '*Convert*' and would now like to get a count of searches for each by date.
Here's my code so far...

```
SELECT        

CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateTimeSelected, 103) AS [Book Date]
,Bathrooms
,Count (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateTimeSelected, 103)) AS 'No of Searches'

FROM dbo.Stats_Bathrooms WITH (NOLOCK)

WHERE (DateTimeSelected BETWEEN GETDATE() - 7 AND GETDATE())

GROUP BY ID, DateTimeSelected, Bathrooms, SessionID
```

Any help *very* much appreciated!

Comment: What RDBMS are you using: SQLServer?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should `GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateTimeSelected, 103), Bathrooms` only:

```
SELECT
    CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateTimeSelected, 103) AS [Book Date]
    ,Bathrooms
    ,Count (CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateTimeSelected, 103)) AS 'No of Searches'
FROM dbo.Stats_Bathrooms WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE (DateTimeSelected BETWEEN GETDATE() - 7 AND GETDATE())
GROUP BY CONVERT(VARCHAR(10), DateTimeSelected, 103), 
         Bathrooms;
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/9192b/1)

This will give you:

```
|  BOOK DATE | BATHROOMS | NO OF SEARCHES |
-------------------------------------------
| 26/07/2013 |         1 |              3 |
| 26/07/2013 |         2 |              4 |
| 26/07/2013 |         3 |              1 |
| 27/07/2013 |         1 |              2 |
```

Comment: Diverse your times in the SQL fiddle demo to really show the purpose of the CONVERT. Otherwise it would return the same results without CONVERT.